# how to include bold tag in my windowsform .cs file?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, datagridview, bold

I currently have the following code:

```
Label lbltxt = new Label(); 
lbltxt.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",
                                      10F,
                                      System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold,
                                      System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,
                                      ((byte)(0)));

lbltxt.Text = dr["Title"].ToString();           
string text = lbltxt.Text;

string s = lbltxt.Text + Environment.NewLine + dr["Description"].ToString();
```

I want to bold the `dr["title"]` and add it to normal `dr["description"]`. I used above code to bold a part and added it to the `dr["description"]`, but it was not working. I'm using this in winforms, i added dataset to datagridview and display result in datadridview.

Answer (score 1):

Your question made me realize that you need a RichTextBox version of a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn.  I Googled that and found a promising article on codeproject.com:

[RichTextBox Cell in a DataGridView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/RtfInDataGridView.aspx)

I've never used the code before so I'm not sure if there are any serious limitations, but it looks like something you can use.

Take a look at the screenshot I made after downloading and running the project:

[image]

Notice I've added a new line with bolded text at cell position 0, 0.

Answer (score 0):

This should format your Title into `<b>` tags for you.

```
lbltxt.Text = string.Format("<b>{0}</b>", dr["Title"].ToString());
```

-**Edit**-

Turns out Html tags don't render in the Text attribute. Try styling it instead.

```
lbltxt.Style["font-weight"] == "heavy";
```

Comment: Thank you for your response sir.It was displayed like "<d>Title</b>" in every row,not working Sir.Any other way?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what else to try

Comment: 'Sir' is a bit ott (over the top) especially for the very helpful but nevertheless still grunts on here, yes, including me =)

Comment: @CodeBlend, I found his/her use of the term 'sir' to be a very novel and refreshing concept. I also found it super-hilarious because I'm a woman. XD